Locus of point of intersection of $x+y=m^2+m+1$ and $y-mx=1$, $m$ is a real number
Locus of point of intersection of $x+y=m^2+m+1\cdots (1)$ and $y-mx=1\cdots (2)$
I take $m=(y-1)/x$ from (1) and put it in (2), I get the locus as
$x^3-x^2+x-y^2+2y+x^2y-xy-1=0\cdots (3)$
But the answer is: a parabola or a line.
Can some one explain this?

You may check that your equation $(3)$ factors as $(y-1-x^2)(x+y-1)=0$ giving you a parabola and line.
Given
$$x+y=m^2+m+1 \cdots (1), \quad y-mx=1 \cdots (2)$$
Another way: Subtract $(1)$ and $(2)$ to get $(m+1)x=m(m+1) \implies (x-m)(m+1)=0$
Case $1$: When $m=-1$ from $(2)$ you get one locus as $x+y-1=0$.
Case $2$:  Otherwise put $x=m$, this in $(1)$ to get the other locus as $y=1+x^2$.

Strictly speaking, the subtraction does not give $x=m(m+1)/(m+1)$. It gives $(m+1)x=m(m+1)$, which reduces ti $x=m$ only if $m\not=-1$. The case $m=-1$ would have to be handled separately.

Thanks I have corrected it now.

You have to factor the cubic.
Factoring is as much an art as a science. Here, we try isolating terms of like degree in $y$ so as to form a quadratic equation:
$-y^2+(x^2-x+2)y+(x^3-x^2+x-1)=0$
The discriminant as a function of $x$ is
$(x^2-x+2)^2+4(x^3-x^2+x-1)=x^4+2x^3+x^2=\color{blue}{(x^2+x)^2}.$
Since the discriminant is a squared quantity, solving for $y$ as a function of $x$ will give two rational functions as roots. One of these will be a linear polynomial, thus a line; the other will be quadratic polynomial, thus a parabola.
